# Write a for loop that prints from startNumber to lastNumber

Tags: c++, for-loop

I can't figure out how to do a for loop with a start number of -5 and end number of 6.

```
int startNumber
int endNumber
int I 

startNumber = -5
endNumber = 6;

for( i = -5; i > endNumber; i++)
 cout << i << /n
```

Comment: Why `i > endNumber`? Is -5 greater than 6?

Comment: You've mistakenly reversed the comparison sign, it should be like this:
for( i = startNumber; i < endNumber; i++)

Comment: Also you have several other syntax errors in that code. This isn't remotely valid c++.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a couple of things here (assuming this is your full code and not just a snippet

```
#include <iostream> // allows you to use cout functions etc

int main() // function for your program to run
{
    int startNumber = -5; // initialise variables
    int endNumber = 6;

    // this loops from startNumber to endNumber going up by 1 each loop
    for(int i = startNumber; i <= endNumber; i++)
        std::cout << i << std::endl //cout prints the value i

    return 0;
}
```